# shell loop through file lines and replace each line

Tags: shell

I am really new to shell scripting, but here is the situation:
I have a text file that contains the following :

```
int1, operationName1
int2, operationName2
int3, operationName3
```

In a nutshell, the file contains some operations (operationNameX) and the number of days remaining to execute each operation (intX).

I want to write a script that will be executed once per day and removes 1 from each int. for example if "test.txt" contains:

```
2, operation1
4, operation2
3, operation3
```

after the execution of the script, it will contain:

```
1, operation1
3, operation2
2, operation3
```

any idea on what should I do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try Awk.  It's incredibly powerful and perfect for this kind of thing:

```
awk -F, '//{VAL=$1; print (VAL-1)", "$2}' test.txt
```

This sets the field separator to a comma (whitespace, by default), assigns the first element (the integer) to a variable named VAL and then prints out VAL-1 followed by a comma, a space and the original second column.

Comment: thank you, but can I overwrite the file content by the output of awk??

Comment: You could but it's generally a bad idea to overwrite your source file atomically.  You could `cat test.txt | awk ... > test.txt`.  I'd recommend doing it in two steps, though.